# Iterate over first N rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the suggested way to iterate over the rows in pandas like you would in a file? For example:

```
LIMIT = 100
for row_num, row in enumerate(open('file','r')):
    print (row)
    if row_num == LIMIT: break
```

I was thinking to do something like:

```
for n in range(LIMIT):
    print (df.loc[n].tolist())
```

Is there a built-in way to do this though in pandas?

Comment: Is there any particular thing that you want to do with the first N rows? The reason for asking this question is that  `df.iterrows()` is really slow and should be avoided if possible (usually it can be avoided).

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: @gorjan I'm doing some sort of `if` logic on each of these rows.

Comment: @gorjan do you want to post an answer with the more performant answer? Or am I already doing it with `df.loc` ?

Comment: @David542  Let me know if what I posted is sufficient for you.

Comment: `df.head(100).itertuple()` as my new answer suggested would do.

Comment: Would you consider un-accepting my answer so that I can delete it? Clearly knh190's is much better.

Comment: @timgeb done...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Hasn't anyone answered the simple solution?

```
for row in df.head(5).itertuples():
    # do something
```

---

Take a peek at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas).

Comment: btw, `df.head(5).iterrows()` works too

Comment: This is art, truly

Answer (score 12):

I know others have suggested iterrows but no-one has yet suggested using iloc combined with iterrows. This will allow you to select whichever rows you want by row number:

```
for i, row in df.iloc[:101].iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Though as others have noted if speed is essential an apply function or a vectorized function would probably be better.

```
>>> df
     a    b
0  1.0  5.0
1  2.0  4.0
2  3.0  3.0
3  4.0  2.0
4  5.0  1.0
5  6.0  NaN
>>> for i, row in df.iloc[:3].iterrows():
...     print(row)
... 
a    1.0
b    5.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
a    2.0
b    4.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
a    3.0
b    3.0
Name: 2, dtype: float64
>>>
```

Comment: This doesnt works.

Answer (score 3):

You have `values`, `itertuples` and `iterrows` out of which `itertuples` performs best as benchmarked by [fast-pandas](https://github.com/mm-mansour/Fast-Pandas).

[image]

Comment: @timgeb perhaps you can show each of the three approaches in code and I can answer your question?

Comment: friendly ping: @timegb you can edit my answer further if you feel it is incomplete. I tried helping from my end. :)

Comment: @meW no worries, I could have made myself clearer. Reminding us which method is faster is valuable, but it does not explain how to iterate only the first N rows.

Comment: @timgeb I'll ensure answer completeness from next time :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iterools.islice` to take the first `n` items from `iterrows`:

```
import itertools
limit = 5
for index, row in itertools.islice(df.iterrows(), limit):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must iterate over the dataframe, you should use the `iterrows()` method:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, can you limit it within the `iterrows()` or do you need to use the `limit` approach?

Comment: You'll need to use a limit approach in one form or another.  Because `iterrows` returns a generator, you can call the `next` method `N` times to take the first N rows.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that you want to use something like an if I would do the following:

```
limit = 2
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3], "col2": [4,5,6], "col3": [7,8,9]})
df[:limit].loc[df["col3"] == 7]
```

This would select the first two rows of the data frame, then return the rows out of the first two rows that have a value for the `col3` equal to 7. Point being you want to use `iterrows` only in very very specific situations. Otherwise, the solution can be vectorized.

I don't know what exactly are you trying to achieve so I just threw a random example.